# Allegro 5 font display problems

Tags: c++, fonts, allegro, freetype, freetype2

Using Allegro 5 (5.0.10-1), for some reason text is displayed in a really strange way - it's cut off at certain parts and letters are sometimes not on the same line.
See the image below.

[image: Text displayed strangely]

I'm loading the font like this:

```
this->font = al_load_font ("fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf", 12, 0)
```

And drawing the text like this:

```
al_draw_text (this->font, al_map_rgb (0xE0, 0xE0, 0xE0),
    20.5, 4.5, 0, this->lbl.c_str ());
```

where lbl holds the text I want to output.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Maybe add freetype or freetype2 tag?? I've seen this sometimes before in apps that use freetype. Can't suggest anything else at the moment

Comment: Does turning on multi-sampling help? See `al_set_new_display_option()`.

Comment: That does make it look much better (http://i.imgur.com/iD3moAP.png). The letters are still misaligned on smaller font sizes. But for slightly larger sizes, it looks somewhat decent.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this because you try to draw it at non-integer coordinates (20.5,4.5). Generally, you should only draw text on integer coordinates to avoid this sort of problem.